# Upgrading Lubuntu 16.04 => 18.04 , using do-release-upgrade , cannot remove linux-image-4.4.x due to dpkg error

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, lubuntu, dpkg

after upgrade everything seems fine , except when i want to update/upgrade/install packages , dpkg fails to remove old unused kernels.

after running `sudo apt upgrade` the following error happens:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.4.0-210-generic
The following packages have been kept back:
  gimp-gmic php-curl
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,021 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,255 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 599373 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-210-generic (4.4.0-210.242) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-210-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: 2012: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-210-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.4.0-210-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-210-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**EDIT 1:**
after using @N0rbert solution , i think kernel is upgraded correctly , and now CLI upgrade just crashes and show's no error , and update-manager show's the following error , should i force install?

[image]

**EDIT 2** : thanks to @guiverc comment, because of extensive changes in 18.04 and above , a fresh install is suggested by Lubuntu team . i will install 20.04 .

Comment: There's no upgrade path from 16.04 directly to 20.04 in any Ubuntu or flavors let alone Lubuntu where the recent DE changes strongly recommend a fresh install even if you were going from 18.04 to 20.04. So, don't. Do your backups and install fresh.

Comment: `/etc/default/grub` is a critical file.  You will need to replace or rebuild it to fix this.

Comment: FYI: standard Ubuntu LTS releases have 5 years support but flavor like Lubuntu only 3 years, therefore "Lubuntu 18.04" is already out of support. Again, do your backups and install 20.04.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thank you i didn't know it was outdated, i will try fresh install 20.04 tomorrow

Comment: @user10489 thank you , how can i do that?

Comment: @BabakKarimiAsl see answer below, you can heal your currently running system. The damage is not severe.

Comment: For the new problem, please post a new question. The first one has been answered and you accepted an answer to it. It's not cool to change the question into something that has not been answered.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* only had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: Also please note:   beyond 18.04 being the last Lubuntu to use LXDE, and thus *the end of the road* (https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/) with regards upgrades; a re-install was necessary for later releases due to desktop change.  eg. Reading https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/ you'll read "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace this `/etc/default/grub` configuration file with default contents using single long command below:

```
cat <<\EOF | sudo tee /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
EOF
```

and then resume package upgrade on current Ubuntu version by running `sudo update-grub` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Then reboot and use `update-manager -c` or `sudo do-release-upgrade` to upgrade to next Ubuntu version (probably 18.04 LTS). Repeat the procedure to upgrade 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS.

Comment: thank you very much , it solved the kernel issue , now there is new problem :D , please see my edit

Comment: @BabakKarimiAsl please post a new question